# Importing file in reactjs

Tags: reactjs, visual-studio

My project looks something like this

```
/src  
   /components       
     /Homepage
       Homepage.js.
   App.js  
   index.css
   index.js
```

I want to import Homepage.js to App.js. I did
 `import About from './Components/./Homepage/Homepage';` but it doesn't work. Any ideas on how I should import it correctly

Answer (score 0):

So if you would like to import Homepage.js to App.js, correct your import statement as below

`import About from './components/Homepage/Homepage'`

There is a small typo in your import statement which is failing. :)
I would suggest using VSCode, it helps a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you have `export default About` in your Homepage.js, then you can use `import About from './components/Homepage/Homepage';` in App.js

If you just use `export About`, then you can use `import { About } from './components/Homepage/Homepage';` in App.js.

1. Make sure you exported the object or function.
2. Use the correct import path